# What is the current standard way to deploy a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, passenger, capistrano

Up until now I've been deploying Rails apps to our Apache/Passenger setup using a simple Rake task that I wrote. I haven't tried to mess around with Capistrano or [Vlad the Deployer](http://rubyhitsquad.com/Vlad_the_Deployer.html).

However, now more developers are coming on board, and I'm interesting in arranging things so that the deployment process runs the tests first and won't deploy unless they all pass. So I'm revisiting the question.

It's been a while since I looked into this. What are most people doing these days? Still using Capistrano? Writing individual Rake tasks? Something else?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Capistrano is still the standard for typical Rails deployments, yes.

Comment: Agreed, capistrano is the way to go. Very flexible and extendable, easy to write deployment recipes to do just about anything under the sun.

Answer (score 1):

We're using Capistrano and Integrity for a CI server. Integrity is quite easy to hack on and you could really easily set it up to automatically deploy on a pass of all tests, and I'd recommend all of them as good tools; Integrity has plenty of plugins available. We currently have Integrity spit out each build's pass/fail and code coverage % into an IRC channel and manually deploy.